# Mongoose schema validation: Error for empty string when validating a non-required field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, validator.js

I have a mongoose schema, like,

```
let Employee = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
    validate: {
      validator: validator.isEmail,
      message: "{Value} is not valid"
    }
  },
  contactNum: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: validator.isMobilePhone,
      message: "{Value} is not valid"
    }
  },
  salary: {
    type: String
  }
});
```

I am validating for contactNum field to be a 'mobile phone number' but following error is occurring **when I left contact number field empty** -

> message: "Employee validation failed: contactNum: {Value} is not
>   valid", name: "ValidationError"

However, I don't want the contactNum field to be `required`.

Comment: It is not  required but if you read the message it clearly says that the value passed from contact number field did not get over validation in you schema, so you have to update your validator  in order to allow null or empty values

Comment: Please can you explain that how can I update my validator to allow null or empty values.

Comment: Best way is to use a regex expression and have a custom function which allow null values , or maybe there could be another way to check if the phone value is not empty , and then to check if is valid number before you add into database so you update schema and delete isValidPhone validator .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using validator.js module of npm for validation purposes in my mongoose schema and therefore I checked it's documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) and with some more research I finally found the answer.

The schema can be updated to not validate for `mobile phone number` if value is empty, like -

```
contactNum: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    validate: {
      validator: (value) => {

        // Check if value is empty then return true.
        if (value === "") {
          return true;
        }

        // If value is empty will not validate for mobile phone.
        return validator.isMobilePhone(value);
      },
      message: "{VALUE} is not valid"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your validator.isMobilePhone() into accepting null or empty values.
And change your schema like this

```
 contactNum: {
    type: String,
    required:false,
    validate: {
      validator: validator.isMobilePhone,
      message: "{Value} is not valid"
    }
  }
```

by setting required to false you can achieve what you want.

change your validator js function like this

```
Validator.isMobilePhone('telephone', function(value, requirement, attribute) { // requirement parameter defaults to null
  if(value.toString()==""){return true;}
  return value.match(/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/);
}, 'The :attribute phone number is not in the format XXX-XXX-XXXX.');
```

Comment: I updated my schema's contactNum field to include required as false but still throwing same error. And please explain how can I update my validator into accepting null or empty values.

Comment: post  your validator function in the question

Comment: I am using validator.js from npm and validator.isMobilePhone is it's inbuilt function.